# Яндекс практикум основы Phyton тема 5 задача 5 шаг 3

Tags: python, backend

#Помогите решить задачу

> 

Шаг 3
Объявите функцию process_friend(name, query), принимающую имя друга name и запрос query. В этой функции будут обрабатываться запросы, в которых имя — не «Анфиса».
В функции process_friend() напишите ветвление:
если друг с именем name есть в словаре DATABASE:
если переменная query содержит строку 'ты где?' — функция должна вернуть сообщение '{имя_друга} в городе {название_города}'; название города нужно получить из словаря DATABASE.
если переменная query содержит какую-то другую строку — функция должна вернуть сообщение <неизвестный запрос>.
если друга с именем name нет в словаре DATABASE — функция должна вернуть сообщение: У тебя нет друга по имени {имя_друга}.
Теперь нужно дописать функцию process_query().
Добавьте в ветвление if name == 'Анфиса' блок else: если запрос начинается не с имени «Анфиса» — верните результат вызова функции process_friend(), передав в неё два аргумента: имя друга и текст вопроса.
Добавьте новые вызовы функции

```
process_query():
print(process_query('Коля, что делать?'))
print(process_query('Антон, ты где?'))
```

, пишет :

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "main.py", line 63, in <module>
>
>   File "main.py", line 38, in process_query
>
> NameError: name 'name' is not defined**
> ```

#это мой код :

> ```
>      DATABASE = {
>     'Серёга': 'Омск',
>     'Соня': 'Москва',
>     'Миша': 'Москва',
>     'Дима': 'Челябинск',
>     'Алина': 'Красноярск',
>     'Егор': 'Пермь',
>     'Коля': 'Красноярск'
> }
> def process_friend(name, query):
>     # Проверяем, есть ли имя name среди ключей словаря
>     if name in DATABASE:
>         name = DATABASE.value()
>         return f'{name} в городе {city}'
>     else:
>         return f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}'# Если имя есть в словаре - проверяем, что передано в query
>     if query == 'ты где?':
>             # Если в переменной query передан вопрос "ты где?" -
>             # получаем из словаря значение (название города) по ключу name
>         city = DATABASE[name]            
>         return f'{name} в городе {city}'# тут строка "имя_друга в городе название_города"
>
>
> def format_friends_count(friends_count):
>     if friends_count == 1:
>         return '1 друг'
>     elif 2 <= friends_count <= 4:
>         return f'{friends_count} друга'
>     else:
>         return f'{friends_count} друзей'
>
> def process_query(query):
>     elements = query.split(', ')
>     if elements[0] == 'Анфиса':
>         return process_anfisa(elements[1])
>     else:
>         return process_friend(element[0],query)
>         
> def process_anfisa(query):
>     if query == 'сколько у меня друзей?':
>         count = len(DATABASE)
>         # Вызовите функцию format_friends_count() и передайте в неё count.
>         # Отредактируйте строку ниже: в ней должно использоваться выражение, 
>         # которое вернёт функция format_friends_count()
>         return f'У тебя {format_friends_count(count)}.'
>     elif query == 'кто все мои друзья?':
>         friends_string = ', '.join(DATABASE)
>         return f'Твои друзья: {friends_string}'
>     elif query == 'где все мои друзья?':
>         unique_cities = set(DATABASE.values())
>         cities_string = ', '.join(unique_cities)
>         return f'Твои друзья в городах: {cities_string}'
>     else:
>         return '<неизвестный запрос>'
>
>
> print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
> print(process_query('Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?'))
> print(process_query('Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'))
> print(process_query('Анфиса, где все мои друзья?'))
> print(process_query('Анфиса, кто виноват?'))
> print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
> print(process_query('Коля, что делать?'))
> print(process_query('Антон, ты где?'))
> ```

[Ссылка на код (если тут криво)](https://dpaste.com/99PDSMQXM)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну да, у вас переменная `name` не определена в функции `process_query()`, а вы ее используете в строке `return process_friend(name,query)`. Судя по контексту, имя у вас находится в `elements[0]`. Попробуйте `return process_friend(elements[0],query)`

Comment: Исправил , пишет Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 63, in <module>

  File "main.py", line 38, in process_query

NameError: name 'element' is not defined

Comment: Потому что имя переменной `elements`, а не element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбираем ошибки по шагам:

1. `name = DATABASE.value()` - если вы хотели получить значение из словаря, а я подозреваю, что это так, то в python значение по ключу получается таким образом: `city = DATABASE[name]`. Переменная `city` у вас также была не задана, поэтому задаем значение переменной, а значение `name` не меняем.
2. В функции `process_friend(name, query):` у вас `return` после if и else, следовательно второе условие if уже не будет работать, так как результат функции возвращается при первом if else.
3. 

```
else:
    return process_friend(elements[0],query) # забыли "s" после "element"
```

Исправленный код:

```
    'Серёга': 'Омск',
    'Соня': 'Москва',
    'Миша': 'Москва',
    'Дима': 'Челябинск',
    'Алина': 'Красноярск',
    'Егор': 'Пермь',
    'Коля': 'Красноярск'
}
def process_friend(name, query):
    # Проверяем, есть ли имя name среди ключей словаря
    if name in DATABASE:
        city = DATABASE[name]
        print f'{name} в городе {city}'
    else:
        print f'У тебя нет друга по имени {name}'# Если имя есть в словаре - проверяем, что передано в query
    if query == 'ты где?':
            # Если в переменной query передан вопрос "ты где?" -
            # получаем из словаря значение (название города) по ключу name
        city = DATABASE[name]            
        return f'{name} в городе {city}'# тут строка "имя_друга в городе название_города"
    else:
        return


def format_friends_count(friends_count):
    if friends_count == 1:
        return '1 друг'
    elif 2 <= friends_count <= 4:
        return f'{friends_count} друга'
    else:
        return f'{friends_count} друзей'

def process_query(query):
    elements = query.split(', ')
    if elements[0] == 'Анфиса':
        return process_anfisa(elements[1])
    else:
        return process_friend(elements[0],query)
        
def process_anfisa(query):
    if query == 'сколько у меня друзей?':
        count = len(DATABASE)
        # Вызовите функцию format_friends_count() и передайте в неё count.
        # Отредактируйте строку ниже: в ней должно использоваться выражение, 
        # которое вернёт функция format_friends_count()
        return f'У тебя {format_friends_count(count)}.'
    elif query == 'кто все мои друзья?':
        friends_string = ', '.join(DATABASE)
        return f'Твои друзья: {friends_string}'
    elif query == 'где все мои друзья?':
        unique_cities = set(DATABASE.values())
        cities_string = ', '.join(unique_cities)
        return f'Твои друзья в городах: {cities_string}'
    else:
        return '<неизвестный запрос>'


print('Привет, я Анфиса!')
print(process_query('Анфиса, сколько у меня друзей?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, где все мои друзья?'))
print(process_query('Анфиса, кто виноват?'))
print(process_query('Соня, ты где?'))
print(process_query('Коля, что делать?'))
print(process_query('Антон, ты где?'))
```

Comment: Отлично , вы почти помогли мне , после всех исправлений даёт ошибку фото ошибки прикладываю в задании

Comment: Измените условие так, что бы `'<неизвестный запрос>'` отображалось на нужный запрос. Подумайте сами хоть немного. Это настолько просто, что если вы сами это не можете сделать, то лучше дальше и не тратить деньги на яндекс.практикум. Какой смысл учиться, если за вас задачи будут решать форумчане? Пробуйте, пытайтесь, основные ошибки я вам исправил.